# Gunicorn worker timeout - Which gunicorn worker sync vs gthread

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I am using Django and Django Rest Framework (DRF) for my project. In production, when I make HTTP requests, Gunicorn module on the server creates another worker to process that request. This process requires two workers: one to handle the Django request and another that is spawned when the Django code makes an HTTP request to the DRF view. After a while, I frequently find myself experiencing long response times, eventually leading to a 502 Gateway Error. Upon examining the logs, I discovered that all my workers were busy and waiting for the DRF response. Simultaneously, different clients made requests, but there were no available workers to handle these new HTTP requests (I am using 3 workers with Gunicorn's default synchronous worker model). How can I manage this situation when there are multiple simultaneous requests?
after this - i modified my application to minimize HTTP calls for internal communication. Previously, I used Django Rest Framework (DRF) views accessed via HTTP requests for internal operations. Now, I've changed it to using direct internal Python function calls instead. I'm considering whether there are additional optimizations or configurations I should implement at the Gunicorn level in production. Despite consulting the official Gunicorn documentation and exploring several articles, I've encountered conflicting information that has left me uncertain about the best course of action.

Comment: Because you dont provide enough information such as your code, task IO or CPU, so I can't tell you what a good config. But you can try use a number `thread` maybe `--workers 2 --threads 20`. if you dont set number thread, it will 1 by default and mean the server will process 1 request at the same time, another request will handle by worker master => it makes many requests stuck by wait first request done